# How do I prevent Application.Match Function giving me a Run-Time Error 91?

Tags: runtime-error, match

I'm trying to find a match in a column, return the range of that match, then display a message box with values derived from cells offset from that match's range. But I get error code 91 when I run this. I'm not a great coder, so any extra details you can provide would be really appreciated, as sometimes I struggle to understand the answers provided if it's too jargony.

I was using the find function, but occasionally, the match I want to find is hidden via filters in the spreadsheet, and I read somewhere that the match function won't be affected by whether the cells are filtered or not.

```
Sub GetInfo2()
Dim Item As String
Dim FindRng As Range

Item = InputBox("What is the item number?", "Item Number")
FindRng = Application.Match(Item, Worksheets("Current Week Summary").Columns(1), 0)
If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("Description: " & FindRng.Offset(0, 4).Value & vbCrLf & _
        "Flyer/FEM: " & FindRng.Offset(0, 1).Value & vbCrLf & _
        "Margin Maker: " & FindRng.Offset(0, 2).Value & vbCrLf & _
        "ISR Week: " & FindRng.Offset(0, 3).Value & vbCrLf & _
        "Amount To Sell: " & Round(FindRng.Offset(0, 7).Value, 0) & vbCrLf & _
        "Cost: $" & FindRng.Offset(0, 18).Value & vbCrLf & _
        "Months of Supply: " & Round(FindRng.Offset(0, 35).Value, 0) & vbCrLf & _
        "E&O Qty: " & FindRng.Offset(0, 17)), vbOKOnly, Item
    
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I did overcome the issue of not being able to search in filtered rows. I ended up using the VLookup Function to find my matches. It apparently searches whether it's filtered or not. I'm still stumped on how to use the match function, so I'd love to know how to do that. But this solved my problem in the interim.

```
Sub GetInfo()
Dim Item As String
Dim Description As String
Dim FlyerFEM As String
Dim MargMak As String
Dim ISR As String
Dim ATS As String
Dim Cost As String
Dim Supply As String
Dim EAO As String

Item = InputBox("What is the item number?", "Item Number")
Description = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Item, Range("A:AJ"), 5, False)
FlyerFEM = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Item, Range("A:AJ"), 2, False)
MargMak = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Item, Range("A:AJ"), 3, False)
ISR = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Item, Range("A:AJ"), 4, False)
ATC = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Item, Range("A:AJ"), 8, False)
Cost = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Item, Range("A:AJ"), 19, False)
Supply = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Item, Range("A:AJ"), 36, False)
EAO = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Item, Range("A:AJ"), 18, False)
 MsgBox ("Description: " & Description & vbCrLf & _
        "Flyer/FEM: " & FlyerFEM & _
        "Margin Maker: " & MargMak & vbCrLf & _
        "ISR Week: " & ISR & vbCrLf & _
        "Amount To Sell: " & Round(ATC, 0) & vbCrLf & _
        "Cost: $" & Cost & vbCrLf & _
        "Months of Supply: " & Supply & vbCrLf & _
        "E&O Qty: " & Round(EAO, 0)), vbOKOnly, Item
End Sub
```